# Call Status Incorrect in Post Param as well as StatusCallback

Tags: twilio

I am using the [Twilio REST API](http://twilio.com/docs/api/rest) to make reminder calls and I'm not getting the correct `CallStatus`.

When a call is ignored or receives no answer, I am still getting completed as a status in both `$_POST['CallStatus']` as well as in `/2010-04-01/Accounts/XXX/Calls/XXX.json` that I call in the `StatusCallback` parameter for the API request.

Below is my code :

```
$client = new Services_Twilio($account_sid, $auth_token);
try
{
    $options = array("StatusCallback" => site_url()."/callsms/endofcall/");
    $call = $client->account->calls->create(
                   '+1xxxxxxxxxx', // From a valid Twilio number
                   '+1xxxxxxxxxx', // Call this number
                   site_url()."/callsms/call_user_xml/",
                   $options
            );
           //return $call->sid;
} catch (Exception $e) {
   echo 'Error starting phone call: ' . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

In the endofcall page I have written :

```
$twilio_configs = $this->config->item('twilio');
$account_sid = $twilio_configs['account_sid'];
$auth_token = $twilio_configs['auth_token'];
// set URL and other appropriate options
$curl = 'https://'.$account_sid.':'.$auth_token.'@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/'.$account_sid.'/Calls/'.$csid.'.json';
$content = file_get_contents($curl);
$result = json_decode($content);
if($result->status=='completed')
{
      //DATABASE ENTRY
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a call goes to voicemail, it will still show up as `completed`. It will only show up as `no-answer` if you don't have voicemail configured and ignore the call.